# Ubuntu machine occasionally looses network connection until restarted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

We have migrated our services to a new dedicated server, everything works well except one very strange problem. Somewhere once in a 3-4 weeks server gets offline. Our investigation shows that the server continues working, but as we have no VNC or other way to connect to it, we can restore the control only be rebooting it. After a reboot, everything works well again.
We see in the syslog file, that there is eth0 failure, but our knowledge is not enough to understand the reason.

We greatly appreciate any help!

Full syslog containing the failure and the start-up after a reboot is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oylE2a-_gXudk5yL9rMVQ6QA75HnnXua/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the part of syslog about the failure itself:

```
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.562497] igb 0000:04:00.0 eth0: PCIe link lost
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565241] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565242] igb: Failed to read reg 0xc030!
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565271] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 3998508 at drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb/igb_main.c:747 igb_rd32.cold+0x3a/0x46 [igb]
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565283] Modules linked in: cpuid tls xt_recent ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt xt_LOG nf_log_syslog xt_comment ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 nft_limit xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nft_compat nft_counter intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common nf_tables edac_mce_amd binfmt_misc libcrc32c nfnetlink kvm_amd ipmi_ssif nls_iso8859_1 kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg crypto_simd drm_vram_helper snd_intel_sdw_acpi cryptd drm_ttm_helper snd_hda_codec rapl ttm snd_hda_core joydev input_leds snd_pci_acp6x snd_hwdep drm_kms_helper wmi_bmof snd_pcm snd_pci_acp5x cec snd_timer rc_core snd snd_rn_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops ccp soundcore snd_pci_acp3x syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt acpi_ipmi ipmi_si ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler mac_hid sch_fq_codel efi_pstore drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid cdc_ether usbnet hid mii igb nvme i2c_algo_bit ahci
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565315]  crc32_pclmul xhci_pci i2c_piix4 nvme_core libahci xhci_pci_renesas dca wmi video
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565321] CPU: 0 PID: 3998508 Comm: kworker/0:0 Not tainted 5.15.0-87-generic #97-Ubuntu
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565323] Hardware name: primeLine Solutions B650D4U/B650D4U, BIOS 1.10.PL01 09/05/2023
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565325] Workqueue: events igb_watchdog_task [igb]
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565331] RIP: 0010:igb_rd32.cold+0x3a/0x46 [igb]
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565337] Code: c7 c6 fc 95 12 c0 e8 ad 64 a8 de 48 8b bb 30 ff ff ff e8 6b 76 3b de 84 c0 74 16 44 89 ee 48 c7 c7 98 a2 12 c0 e8 17 00 9f de <0f> 0b e9 99 01 fe ff e9 b4 01 fe ff 0f b6 d0 be 00 00 04 00 48 c7
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565338] RSP: 0018:ffffc19163677db8 EFLAGS: 00010286
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565339] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9d9b132f8ed0 RCX: 0000000000000027
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565340] RDX: ffff9db9a8020588 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9db9a8020580
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565341] RBP: ffffc19163677dd0 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: 000000000194d238
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565342] R10: 0000000000ffff10 R11: 000000000000000f R12: 00000000ffffffff
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565343] R13: 000000000000c030 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff9d9b1329a340
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565344] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9db9a8000000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565345] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565346] CR2: 000055fc969fd000 CR3: 0000001d00e10000 CR4: 0000000000750ef0
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565347] PKRU: 55555554
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565347] Call Trace:
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565349]  <TASK>
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565351]  ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x1d6/0x2ea
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565355]  ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x1d6/0x2ea
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565358]  ? igb_update_stats+0x84/0x880 [igb]
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565362]  ? show_regs.part.0+0x23/0x29
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565364]  ? show_regs.cold+0x8/0xd
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565366]  ? igb_rd32.cold+0x3a/0x46 [igb]
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565370]  ? __warn+0x8c/0x100
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565373]  ? igb_rd32.cold+0x3a/0x46 [igb]
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565377]  ? report_bug+0xa4/0xd0
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565380]  ? handle_bug+0x39/0x90
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565383]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x19/0x70
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565384]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565387]  ? igb_rd32.cold+0x3a/0x46 [igb]
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565391]  ? igb_rd32.cold+0x3a/0x46 [igb]
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565395]  igb_update_stats+0x84/0x880 [igb]
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565399]  igb_watchdog_task+0xa8/0x480 [igb]
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565403]  process_one_work+0x22b/0x3d0
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565406]  worker_thread+0x53/0x420
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565407]  ? process_one_work+0x3d0/0x3d0
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565408]  kthread+0x12a/0x150
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565410]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565412]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565416]  </TASK>
Feb  9 15:13:40 m23430 kernel: [1122633.565416] ---[ end trace e9520e7cbe879ab3 ]---
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786639] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786649] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (igb): transmit queue 1 timed out
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786661] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:477 dev_watchdog+0x277/0x280
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786668] Modules linked in: cpuid tls xt_recent ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt xt_LOG nf_log_syslog xt_comment ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 nft_limit xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nft_compat nft_counter intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common nf_tables edac_mce_amd binfmt_misc libcrc32c nfnetlink kvm_amd ipmi_ssif nls_iso8859_1 kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg crypto_simd drm_vram_helper snd_intel_sdw_acpi cryptd drm_ttm_helper snd_hda_codec rapl ttm snd_hda_core joydev input_leds snd_pci_acp6x snd_hwdep drm_kms_helper wmi_bmof snd_pcm snd_pci_acp5x cec snd_timer rc_core snd snd_rn_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops ccp soundcore snd_pci_acp3x syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt acpi_ipmi ipmi_si ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler mac_hid sch_fq_codel efi_pstore drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid cdc_ether usbnet hid mii igb nvme i2c_algo_bit ahci
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786783]  crc32_pclmul xhci_pci i2c_piix4 nvme_core libahci xhci_pci_renesas dca wmi video
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786795] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G        W         5.15.0-87-generic #97-Ubuntu
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786798] Hardware name: primeLine Solutions B650D4U/B650D4U, BIOS 1.10.PL01 09/05/2023
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786799] RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x277/0x280
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786804] Code: eb 97 48 8b 5d d0 c6 05 0d d8 67 01 01 48 89 df e8 8e 5f f9 ff 44 89 e1 48 89 de 48 c7 c7 80 fc 4d 9f 48 89 c2 e8 b8 d5 19 00 <0f> 0b eb 80 e9 30 6a 23 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 57 41 56
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786806] RSP: 0018:ffffc19140003e70 EFLAGS: 00010282
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786810] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9d9b132f8000 RCX: 0000000000000000
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786812] RDX: ffff9db9a802cb40 RSI: ffff9db9a8020580 RDI: 0000000000000300
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786813] RBP: ffffc19140003ea8 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: 000000000194e050
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786815] R10: 0000000000ffff0a R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000001
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786816] R13: ffff9d9b021d3940 R14: 0000000000000008 R15: ffff9d9b132f84c0
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786818] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9db9a8000000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786820] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786822] CR2: 000055ffe83dd000 CR3: 0000001d00e10000 CR4: 0000000000750ef0
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786824] PKRU: 55555554
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786825] Call Trace:
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786827]  <IRQ>
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786830]  ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x1d6/0x2ea
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786834]  ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x1d6/0x2ea
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786838]  ? call_timer_fn+0x2c/0x120
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786842]  ? show_regs.part.0+0x23/0x29
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786845]  ? show_regs.cold+0x8/0xd
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786848]  ? dev_watchdog+0x277/0x280
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786850]  ? __warn+0x8c/0x100
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786853]  ? dev_watchdog+0x277/0x280
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786856]  ? report_bug+0xa4/0xd0
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786860]  ? arch_irq_work_raise+0x3a/0x50
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786864]  ? handle_bug+0x39/0x90
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786867]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x19/0x70
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786870]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786873]  ? dev_watchdog+0x277/0x280
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786875]  ? pfifo_fast_enqueue+0x160/0x160
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786878]  call_timer_fn+0x2c/0x120
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786881]  __run_timers.part.0+0x1e3/0x270
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786883]  ? ktime_get+0x46/0xc0
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786886]  ? native_x2apic_icr_read+0x20/0x20
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786889]  ? lapic_next_event+0x20/0x30
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786892]  ? clockevents_program_event+0xad/0x130
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786897]  run_timer_softirq+0x2a/0x60
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786899]  __do_softirq+0xd9/0x2e7
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786902]  irq_exit_rcu+0x94/0xc0
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786905]  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x80/0x90
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786908]  </IRQ>
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786909]  <TASK>
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786910]  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x1b/0x20
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786912] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xd9/0x620
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786916] Code: 3d cc 69 78 61 e8 97 66 67 ff 49 89 c7 0f 1f 44 00 00 31 ff e8 d8 73 67 ff 80 7d d0 00 0f 85 61 01 00 00 fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <45> 85 f6 0f 88 6d 01 00 00 4d 63 ee 49 83 fd 09 0f 87 e7 03 00 00
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786918] RSP: 0018:ffffffff9fc03db8 EFLAGS: 00000246
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786921] RAX: ffff9db9a80314c0 RBX: ffff9d9b12981800 RCX: 0000000000000000
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786922] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000002 RDI: 0000000000000000
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786924] RBP: ffffffff9fc03e08 R08: 0003fd087a7bd0c4 R09: 0000000000000000
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786925] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffffffff9fc03ca8 R12: ffffffff9fee96a0
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786927] R13: 0000000000000003 R14: 0000000000000003 R15: 0003fd087a7bd0c4
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786929]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xc8/0x620
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786931]  ? tick_nohz_stop_tick+0x16a/0x1d0
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786934]  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x50
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786936]  cpuidle_idle_call+0x142/0x1e0
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786939]  do_idle+0x83/0xf0
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786941]  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786944]  rest_init+0xd3/0x100
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786946]  ? acpi_enable_subsystem+0x21d/0x229
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786951]  arch_call_rest_init+0xe/0x23
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786955]  start_kernel+0x4a9/0x4ca
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786957]  x86_64_start_reservations+0x24/0x2a
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786960]  x86_64_start_kernel+0xfb/0x106
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786963]  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786967]  </TASK>
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786968] ---[ end trace e9520e7cbe879ab4 ]---
Feb  9 15:13:45 m23430 kernel: [1122637.786985] igb 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Reset adapter
Feb  9 15:13:46 m23430 systemd-networkd[74560]: eth0: Lost carrier
Feb  9 15:13:46 m23430 kernel: [1122638.619616] igb 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Reset adapter
Feb  9 15:13:46 m23430 systemd-networkd[74560]: eth0: DHCPv6 lease lost
Feb  9 15:13:46 m23430 systemd-timesyncd[74660]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
```

Here is a suspicious part of a start-up part of syslog. But I'm not sure if relates to a problem:

```
Feb  9 15:52:08 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: No valid path found for iwconfig
Feb  9 15:52:08 m23430 dbus-daemon[721]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.network1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service' requested by ':1.4' (uid=0 pid=771 comm="/usr/bin/networkctl list --no-pager --no-legend " label="unconfined")
Feb  9 15:52:08 m23430 dbus-daemon[721]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service not found.
Feb  9 15:52:08 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[771]: WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface NetworkctlListState(idx=1, name='lo', type='loopback', operational='n/a', administrative='unmanaged'): n/a
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 298, in trigger_all
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:     self.handle_state(iface_name,
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 348, in handle_state
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:     raise UnknownState(operational_state)
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: UnknownState: n/a
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface NetworkctlListState(idx=2, name='eth0', type='ether', operational='n/a', administrative='unmanaged'): n/a
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 298, in trigger_all
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:     self.handle_state(iface_name,
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 348, in handle_state
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:     raise UnknownState(operational_state)
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: UnknownState: n/a
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface NetworkctlListState(idx=3, name='eth1', type='ether', operational='n/a', administrative='unmanaged'): n/a
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 298, in trigger_all
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:     self.handle_state(iface_name,
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 348, in handle_state
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:     raise UnknownState(operational_state)
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: UnknownState: n/a
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface NetworkctlListState(idx=4, name='usb0', type='ether', operational='n/a', administrative='unmanaged'): n/a
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 298, in trigger_all
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:     self.handle_state(iface_name,
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 348, in handle_state
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]:     raise UnknownState(operational_state)
Feb  9 15:52:09 m23430 networkd-dispatcher[731]: UnknownState: n/a
```

Comment: Replace the nic and see if the problem persists.